# Android Apps in WindowsPhone 8

Tags: 8.0, android

I need to know is there any software emulator or any other thing through which I can install and play Android apps/games on my WindowsPhone 8 (Lumia 520)

Comment: What app(s) specifically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this moment that is not possible, you can't run Android Apps on Windows Phone, there is no emulator that can do that, nor it can be done directly, there are some rumors that have been rising these days that Microsoft is thinking about using Android Apps, but that's just a rumor for the moment

Comment: Ubuntu was starting on a project to do something similar, but never was finished from what I heard. My guess is that they didn't want Ubuntu to just be another way to run Android apps, and have all Ubuntu devs create Android-apps that ran sort-of-ok on Ubuntu. Windows probably has similar reasons to not make Win-Android compatible layer?

Comment: not even with bluestack?